# ¿Cómo insertar un valor explicito en una columna IDENTITY?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo una tabla cualquiera con una columna de tipo `IDENTITY`, por ejemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE TiposComprobantes (
        Id     INT IDENTITY,
        Nombre VARCHAR(255)
)
```

Sin embargo tengo algunos valores heredados que deseo insertar, si hago lo siguiente:

```
INSERT INTO TiposComprobantes (Id, Nombre) VALUES (1, 'Factura A');
```

Obtengo el siguiente error:

> Msg 544, Level 16, State 1, Line 6 Cannot insert explicit value for
>   identity column in table 'TiposComprobantes' when IDENTITY_INSERT is
>   set to OFF.

¿Cómo resuelvo este `insert` en el caso que no me importen los valores de la columna `IDENTITY`?  ¿y en el caso que si sean importantes?

Comment: Esto parece más la entrada de un blog y no una duda legítima.

Comment: @LuisCazares, no entiendo a que te refieres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una columna del tipo `IDENTITY` no puede recibir un valor explícito, ya que es el motor el que se encarga de completarlo, en este caso con un numérico incremental.

La forma normal de hacer un `INSERT`, dónde dejamos que el motor complete este dato es quitar la columna de la sentencia, por ejemplo:

```
INSERT INTO TiposComprobantes (Nombre) VALUES ('Factura A');
```

Sin embargo, aún siendo un `IDENTITY` puede que necesitemos insertar un valor explícito, por ejemplo en un sistema heredado, tal vez el `ID` ya se encuentre referenciado en otras tablas y debamos mantener esta consistencia. En estos casos podemos "deshabilitar" el comportamiento por defecto del `IDENTITY`, mediante la clausula [`SET IDENTITY_INSERT`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-identity-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), por ejemplo:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT TiposComprobantes ON

INSERT INTO TiposComprobantes (Id, Nombre) VALUES (1, 'Factura A');

SET IDENTITY_INSERT TiposComprobantes OFF
```

Comentarios:

- Con `SET IDENTITY_INSERT <NombreTabla> ON` permitimos la actualización de valores explícitos en la Tabla, una vez hecho esto, siempre que el valor insertado sea superior al máximo de la tabla, se actualiza la semilla del `IDENTITY`.
- Recordar que una columna `IDENTITY` no implica necesariamente que el valor de la misma sea estrictamente único, esto lo define una clave de este tipo.
- Para hacer esto debemos tener permisos de `ALTER` sobre la tabla.
- Solo una tabla puede tener la condición de `IDENTITY_INSERT ON` en la sesión / conexión activa, tratar de hacer lo mismo con otra tabla arrojará un error.